# Characterize the continuous functions with finite right-hand derivative for at least one point of $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(E,d_\infty)$ the metric space of continuous functions defined on $ [0,1] $, with $$ d_\infty(f,g)=\sup\{ |f(x) - g(x)| : x\in [0,1] \}. $$
For all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ let
$$ F_n = \{ f: \exists x_0\in [0,1-1/n] \forall x\in [x_0,1]\left(|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq n(x-x_0)\right) \}. $$
Let $D$ be the set of continuous functions which have a finite
derivate on the right for at least one point of $[0, 1)$. I need to show that
$$ D = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n. $$
This is part of problem 38 of section 8 of Royden's Real Analysis book.

Comment: Hint: the point with finite right derivative is $x_0$.

Comment: This looks wrong to me. Are you sure you want $x_{0} \in [0,1/n]$ and not $x_{0} \in [0,1-1/n]$? Then you should be able to apply the hint given by @Yuval.

Comment: Yes, that is the point @Yuval. And You are right @Theo, thank you.

Comment: You should probably draw a picture. You know that the graph lies below some line on the interval $[x_0, x_0 + \delta]$. Now you also know that the function attains its maximum $M$ somewhere. If the line intersects the vertical line at $x_{0} + \delta$ at a higher point than $M$ then you're done. If not, simply make the line steeper to achieve that.

Comment: Whoa, wait a minute! I only commented on the very first comment with a formula. I didn't see the others (I had a coffee in the meantime and left this page open) and I haven't read them. It seems to me that it should be *much* simpler.

Comment: The other inclusion should follow from the same idea.

Comment: Are both inclusions simpler?

Comment: I think so. Did you understand what I was trying to say in the comment "You should probably draw a picture"?

Comment: Thank you by your help @Theo.

Comment: If you've found the answer, you should add it here, for future reference and other users.

Answer (score 0):

If $f\in D$, then there exists $x_{0}\in\lbrack0,1[$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=\ell\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Hence, if we take $\varepsilon=1$, we can find $0<\delta<1-x_{0}$ such that
$$
\left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}-\ell\right\vert \leq1
$$
for all $x\in\lbrack x_{0},x_{0}+\delta]$. In turn,
$$
\left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\right\vert \leq\left\vert
\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}-\ell\right\vert +|\ell|\leq1+|\ell|.
$$
On the other hand, since $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, the function
$$
g(x):=\left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\right\vert
$$
is well defined and continuous in $[x_{0}+\delta,1]$. Hence, there exists
$$
\max_{x\in\lbrack x_{0}+\delta,1]}g(x)=M.
$$
Thus,
$$
\left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\right\vert \leq\max\{1+|\ell|,M\}
$$
for all $x\in]x_{0},1]$, or equivalently,
$$
\left\vert f(x)-f(x_{0})\right\vert \leq\max\{1+|\ell|,M\}(x-x_{0})
$$
for all $x\in\lbrack x_{0},1]$. Since $x_{0}<1$, we can now take $n$ so large
that $x_{0}<1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $n\geq\max\{1+|\ell|,M\}$. This shows that
$f\in F_{n}$, and so
$$
D\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}.
$$